# Is there a way to drop a unique constraint in postgres 10.6 without an exclusive lock?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

Is there a way to drop a unique constraint in postgres 10.6 without an exclusive lock? The table I am referring to here is used quite frequently and thus I am concerned about the exclusive lock. Is there any statistic as to the time it will take for postgres to execute the drop? Basically that time will account for downtime in my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be very fast. The only problem might be long running transactions, which could block you and others that have to queue behind you.

Find a window with no long running transactions, and you will be fine.

Comment: I'm trying to find data to support this so I can suggest this as an option to a peer. Do you have any references you could point me to?

Comment: You can easily test it. Removing a file and changing some metadata doesn't take long.